# Flex list items as tooltips for combo box items

Tags: apache-flex

How to make list items as tool tips for combo box items?

Comment: to use a List control as tooltip (instead of the default label) or use the contents of the list as tooltip text?

Answer (score 0):

import mx.events.ListEvent; import mx.managers.ToolTipManager;
                import mx.controls.ToolTip;

```
        public var myTip:ToolTip;

        private function fnInit():void
        {
            cmb.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER,fnCreToolTip);
            cmb.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OUT,fnCreToolTip);
            cmb.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE,fnCreToolTip);
        }
        private function fnCreToolTip(e:ListEvent):void
        {
            switch(e.type)
            {
                case ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER:
                {
                    //creates a tooltip.
                    myTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(array2[e.rowIndex].tooltip,stage.mouseX+10,stage.mouseY) as ToolTip; // array2 is id of arraylist  
                    break;
                }
                case ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OUT:
                {
                    //destroy the created tooltip, so that we can create a new one for others.
                    ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(myTip);
                    break;
                }
                case ListEvent.CHANGE:
                {
                    //destroy the created tooltip, so that we can create a new one for others.
                    ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(myTip);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In flex 4 create your own item renderer:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground = "true"
                toolTip="{data.description}">
<...>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

where description is a property of object you pass to Combobox via addItem().
(e.g. I pass an XML so I do data.@description)